# Is it beneficial to export views and store it as a module?

Tags: views

So in an attempt to further optimize my app, I thought it would be wise if I store the Views in a module using the export tool.

Are there any advantages to gain by doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The biggest benefit is that you can have your views stored in a version control system like Git or SVN. I maybe mistaken but I don't think there are really performance benefits on doing this.

Some documentation to help you out: http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views

Comment: Doesn't it save a trip to the database when fetching view info?